# Working example of blueprint (subrequest) to create a paragraph and associated entity?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I'm using the [subrequests](https://www.drupal.org/project/subrequests) and [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) modules.  Without a code example, it's daunting to try to build a working blueprint for the subrequest, when I haven't used either module before.

I have consulted the output from the openapi module, which attempts to document the body structure for each entity.  However, this documentation is not very helpful in building a blueprint for a subrequest, partly because it appears to include many keys that won't be necessary in the blueprint.

I'll post a code sample representing my best current guess, but it's not close enough that I have even tried a request:

```
  var my_entity_type = 'apples'
  var my_paragraph_type = 'oranges'

  var body1 = {
    "data": {
      "type": my_paragraph_type,
      "attributes": {
        // I don't know if it's necessary to pass attributes when first creating the paragraph.
      }
    },
    "relationships": {
      "?????": {
        // Yes, my paragraph type itself has relationships.  Not sure if I will need to get
        // all the syntax right to see a good result, or if I can build up to it.
      }
    }
  }

  var body2 = {
    "data": {
      "type": my_entity_type+"--"+atype,
      "attributes": {
        "name": {
          "value": input.label
        },
        "notes": {
          "value": input.notes
        }
      }
    },
    "relationships": {
      "products": {
        "data": {
          "type": "paragraph--"+my_paragraph_type,
          "id": "{{/req-1@/data/uuid}}" // Pure guess.
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var auth = myAuthObject

  var blueprint = 
  [
    {
      'requestId': 'req-1',
      'uri': '/paragraph/'+my_paragraph_type,
      'action': 'create',
      'body': body1,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+auth.access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
      },
    },
    {
      'requestId': 'req-2',
      'uri': '/my_entity/'+my_entity_type,
      'action': 'create',
      'body': body2,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+auth.access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
      },
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I have some working code now for posting (actually PATCH-ing) the paragraph data to my entity.  So from here, it shouldn't be hard to set up the subrequest blueprint.  I'll post my code when it's done.

Comment: This is not a subrequest blueprint but is a working js example of a PATCH request to update a paragraph field, using fetch.  https://pastebin.com/d39y0FD0